# How to generate the thumbnail url for the video files in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an input file dynamically. When I upload the local video files and the info I am getting is the name and size of the file and other info etc which are in the screenshot that I have uploaded. I am trying to generate the thumburl but its not entering into the video's "addeventlistener" and not executing further.

```
   //adding input file dynamically
   store.setAttribute("class", "card no-border");
   store.innerHTML = `<div class="container1">
            <img src="assets/images/image 209.png" alt="Avatar" class="right" style="width:100%;">
            <p class="text-right">` + message + `</p>
            <input type="file" id="files" onchange="handleFileSelect(this,` + doc.id + `)" onclick="this.value=null;"  accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png image/heic video/mp4" multiple>
             </div>`;
   store_row.append(store);
   document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = store_row.innerHTML;

  function handleFileSelect(e,docid) {
    for (var j = 0; j < length; j++) {
      if(file.type.match('video')){
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var video = document.createElement('video');
        video.src=window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
        document.querySelector('.divClasshere').appendChild(video);
        document.querySelector('.divClasshere').appendChild(canvas);
        video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(){
          setTimeout(() => draw(video, thecanvas, img), 500)
         }, false);
    function draw( video, thecanvas, img ){
          thecanvas
          .getContext('2d')
          .drawImage( video, 0, 0, thecanvas.width, thecanvas.height);

           console.log("thecanvas.toDataURL",thecanvas.toDataURL())
           }
        }
     }
```

}
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors??

Comment: I am not getting any errors and also video listener is also working.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things here

first you are not accepting video type files

```
accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png image/heic"
```

change it to

```
 accept="image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png,image/heic,video/mp4"
```

second after creating video element you are not setting the src

```
   var video = document.createElement('video');
   video.src=window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
```

third after you create these elements you are not appending to dom

```
  document.querySelector('.divClasshere').appendChild(video);
  document.querySelector('.divClasshere').appendChild(canvas);
```

Above things are said based on the code you provided.

Try running this snippet.

```js
    document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('change', function (event) {
        let file = event.target.files[0];
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        document.querySelector('.playground').appendChild(canvas);
        if (file.type.match('image')) {
            //for images    
            let img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
            document.querySelector('.playground').appendChild(img);
        } else if (file.type.match('video')) {
            //for video
            let video = document.createElement('video');
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
            video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
                setTimeout(() => draw(video, canvas), 500)
            }, false);
            video.muted = true;
            video.playsInline = true;
            video.play();
            document.querySelector('.playground').appendChild(video);
        }

    })

    function draw(video, canvas) {
        canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
```

```css
    video{
        width: 269px;
    }
    canvas{
        width: 269px;
    }
```

```html
<input type="file" />
<div class="playground">
</div>
```

Comment: I Just need only thumbnail URL and don't want to set it as src for image tag. So still do i need to append those elements to dom.

Comment: I have added the third step in the code but  now I m getting this error - "TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null".

Comment: ".divClasshere" means your HTML div element's class.Ive updated the solution with snippet.Please run it

Comment: I did not initialize any div and I don't need any div, so how do I proceed.

Comment: Actually I need only the thumbnail URL and I want to save that url in the database.

Comment: Use canvas.toDataURL(file.type) more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Comment: Ok, I got the url and how to get in the video listener method. I have added this line "return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0)" in the draw method.

Comment: Listener callback will be called only after video to dom